# There are 2 versions Visual Studio Code Installer, user and System Installer. How do I determine which version I am using?

Tags: visual-studio-code

There are 2 versions Visual Studio Code Installer, user and System Installer.

I've forgotten which version I installed. How do I determine which version I am using?

```
Versión: 1.40.2 (system setup)
Commit: f359dd69833dd8800b54d458f6d37ab7c78df520
Date: 2019-11-25T14:54:45.096Z
Electron: 6.1.5
Chrome: 76.0.3809.146
Node.js: 12.4.0
V8: 7.6.303.31-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.17134
```

Comment: `(system setup)` would seem to answer your question, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Help/About says `(user setup)` and yours says `(system setup)` so that must be your answer.

```
Version: 1.40.2 (user setup)
Commit: f359dd69833dd8800b54d458f6d37ab7c78df520
Date: 2019-11-25T14:54:45.096Z
Electron: 6.1.5
Chrome: 76.0.3809.146
Node.js: 12.4.0
V8: 7.6.303.31-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19037
```

and I did not do the System install version.

Comment: Thank you so much! btw, how to copy that info as text?

Comment: @yigre20cn probably the Copy button beside the OK button.